# Graficar sucesivamente las horas de un día usando subplots en python

Tags: python, bucle-for, matplotlib

Estoy queriendo graficar la amplitud versus el tiempo de todo un día. El archivo donde se encuentra la data es de formato fits, donde el tiempo se muestra de la siguiente manera:

```
[ 0  1  2 ... 86397  86398  86399]
```

Este tiempo esta en segundos y, por otro lado, la amplitud esta en dB y se representa como:

```
[ -28.3  -27.84 -29.88 ... 0.18  -0.92  -0.28]
```

Mi código en python para poder leer la data y graficarla para todo un día es:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python

from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
import os, sys
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time
import matplotlib
from datetime import datetime

#Dimensiones de la figura a graficar
fig_size = [18, 20]
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = fig_size

data_vlf = fits.open('PLO-20171018.fits')
t = pylab.transpose(data_vlf[0].data)[0]
time_vlf = t.astype(int)
time_format = [str(timedelta(seconds=s)) for s in time_vlf]
t_format = '%H:%M:%S'
date_vlf = [datetime.strptime(i, t_format).time() for i in time_format]
ch = pylab.transpose(data_vlf[0].data)[6]

pylab.plot(date_vlf, ch, color='black')
plt.legend(['Channel 6'])
plt.xlabel('Time UT')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.show()
```

Pero también deseo ver como evoluciona la amplitud cada hora del día, para ello, escribí el siguiente código:

```py
h_i = 0
h_i_2 = 3600
h_f = 21600

for i in range(1, 7):
    for num1 in range(h_i, h_f, 3600):
        for num2 in range(h_i_2, h_f+1, 3600):
            t_1 = date_vlf[num1:num2]
            ch_1 = ch[num1:num2]
    plt.subplot(3, 2, i)
    pylab.plot(t_1, ch_1)
    plt.xlabel('1 hour (UT)')
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.show()
```

Sin embargo, solo grafica una hora específica y no de cada hora en el día, en que se debe modificar mi código. Sigo aprendiendo el lenguaje de python, si mi código se puede mejorar agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como consejo general, cuando uses Numpy/Pandas no te alejes de ambos en lo posible, son tus amigos. Es tentador recurrir a código Python crudo, pero en la mayoría de las situaciones numpy/pandas ofrecen versiones vectorizadas y mucho más eficientes de lo que puedes conseguir con Python "normal".

Dicho esto,espero haber entendido bien el problema. Dado que partes de un array NumPy con el tiempo en segundos, puedes conseguir un array de tipo Datetime con solo hacer:

```
date_vlf = t.astype('datetime64[s]')
```

Si mantienes tus arrays como arrays NumPy, puedes aprovecharlos para separar por horas los datos con solo usar `reshape`:

```
>>> date_hours = date_vlf.reshape(24, 3600)
>>> ch_hours = ch.reshape(24, 3600)
```

Voy a generar dos arrays `t` y `ch` (aleatorio) para reproducir tu código en los ejemplos:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pylab


#data_vlf = fits.open('PLO-20171018.fits')
#t = pylab.transpose(data_vlf[0].data)[0]
#ch = pylab.transpose(data_vlf[0].data)[6]

t  = np.arange(0, 86400)
ch = np.random.uniform(low=-30, high=1, size=(86400,))

date_vlf = t.astype('datetime64[s]')

#Dimensiones de la figura a graficar
fig_size = [18, 20]
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = fig_size

pylab.plot(date_vlf, ch, color='black')

t_format = '%H:%M:%S'
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter(t_format)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

plt.legend(['Channel 6'])
plt.xlabel('Time UT')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mostrar gráficos por horas puedes hacer algo así:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pylab


#data_vlf = fits.open('PLO-20171018.fits')
#t = pylab.transpose(data_vlf[0].data)[0]
#ch = pylab.transpose(data_vlf[0].data)[6]

t  = np.arange(0, 86400)
ch = np.random.uniform(low=-30, high=1, size=(86400,))

date_vlf = t.astype('datetime64[s]')

date_hours = date_vlf.reshape(24, 3600)
ch_hours = ch.reshape(24, 3600)

t_format = '%H:%M:%S'
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter(t_format)

hours = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # Horas a mostrar

for i, hour in enumerate(hours):
    date_h = date_hours[hour]
    ch_h = ch_hours[hour]

    plt.subplot(np.ceil(len(hours) / 2) , 2, i + 1)
    pylab.plot(date_h, ch_h, color="black")
    plt.xlabel('{} hour (UT)'.format(hour))
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]